# Is there a way to get ProxyHTMLURLMap to match more than once per tag attribute?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-security, mod-proxy-html

I have a problem that seems to be caused by resources being called with img tags that look like this:

```
<img 
class="alignnone size-full" 
title="some title"
src="https://new.url.com/some.jpeg" alt="" width="612" height="408" 
srcset="https://new.url.com/some.jpeg 612w, https://old.url.com/some-300x200.jpg 300w" 
sizes="(max-width: 612px) 100vw, 612px">
```

ProxyHTMLURLMap successfully replaces the first URL within the attribute "srcset" but never more than the first.

I don't see anything in the manual that could address this, any help is much appreciated.

I am interested in **any** open source Linux compatible solutions even if outside Apache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a limited workaround for this issue.

If each ProxyHTMLURLMap can replace only one matched occurrence, we need to add more directives like that.

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap "https://old.url.com/" "https://new.url.com/" Rl
ProxyHTMLURLMap " https://old.url.com/" " https://new.url.com/" Rl
ProxyHTMLURLMap ", https://old.url.com/" ", https://new.url.com/" Rl
ProxyHTMLURLMap "w, https://old.url.com/" "w, https://new.url.com/" Rl
```

These four directives can replace up to 4 instances of https://old.url.com

"R" flag is needed to process regular expressions.
"l" flag is needed to avoid stopping after first (second, third) match occurs.

It seems to work for me.